# XCode Archive: "No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found."

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I have no idea why, but on XCode, to access the Archive button in Product, I change my device to a generic IOS device. Whenever I do that and press the Archive button, I get this message: "No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found." I have no idea how to fix this and I've searched. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to submit your app to `AppStore`, you need to sign your app with `Distribution` certificate and valid provision profile.

You can have a look at this [example](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/32957-how-do-i-create-a-distribution-profile-for-ios)